# how to implement a carousel of uitableviews?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, icarousel

I need to implement a circular **scrolling carousel** in which each view in it is a **table view** with data loaded from the internet.

I really don´t know which is the best **approach** to implement it, i was thinking maybe in using nick lockwood's **icarousel** but i am not completely sure.

Any thoughts on which is the best approach?

Thanks for any insights that you can provide me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing a project using the iCarousel right now, you can supply your own views for the carousel in

```
- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
```

there shouldn't be any problem with adding UITableViews as subviews to the returned view (or just return the tables).

You might run into some problems when trying to scroll the tables though, I've run into troubles with UITouchGestureRecognizers on my custom views, in the end had to disable those of the iCarousel.

Comment: Thanks i wil give it a try then to see how it goes.