# UITableviews as subviews of iCarousel adds swipe issue

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiswipegesturerecognizer, icarousel

I have a iCarousel view which contains list of UITableViewControllers as subview and they work fine. The only problem I have is when user touches the UITableview to move left or right they can't because the touches aren't passed to iCarousel Class because they are catch by UITableview.

How can I achieve the task that user has the flexibility to move/swipe between different UITableviews even when the touches start from a UITableView.

The functionality that I am implementing is pretty similar to
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15218377/how-to-display-the-list-of-table-view-as-cover-flow-in-ios6-1/15220578#comment28284389_15220578)
and I have seen [another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11228178/how-to-implement-a-carousel-of-uitableviews) but couldn't find it much of an help.

Comment: Did you find solution for this?

Comment: Not yet, I changed the approach by implementing in native UIScrollView. But I would like to know its solution with iCarousel.

Comment: I created the scenario and couldn't reproduce the behavior you describe. I can't even edit the cell (which is done exactly by swiping to the side). Instead the iCarousel scrolls. Are you sure you aren't adding any swipe gesture recognizers, pan gesture recognizers or scrollviews to the cell which would catch the gesture?

Comment: can you share your code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Nick Lockwood and the contributors...
They fixed the problem by October 21st. More details on what else has been fixed and added can be seen [here on Github](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel/network)